HTML&CSS to PDF using DevExpress
I want to make PDF from HTML which I am getting as a string.
It has inline CSS too.
My company is using DevExpress Package for handling documents.
I have written below method for it -
public Stream Testing(string htmlString)
{
    RichEditDocumentServer richEditDocumentServer = new();
    richEditDocumentServer.HtmlText = htmlString;

    MemoryStream ms = new();
    richEditDocumentServer.ExportToPdf(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}

Here my HTML & CSS are not getting properly applied in PDF.  It applies them both but not in a correct way. I am not getting same result as when I see my html in browser.
Below is my HTML with CSS you can check in any online HTML viewer.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="font-md">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Result Master View</title>

</head>

<body class="hrms2 ">




    <div class="body-content">
        <main class="main-content">


            <div class=" customFormPage">
                <!-- <div class="filter-row row d-flex align-items-baseline justify-content-between mb-4">
                    <h5 class="col-md-6">Paybill Preview</h5>
                    <div class="search-filter-upload col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <div class="searchBar">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="has-float-label">
                                    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="Search" placeholder="Search">
                                    <label for="Search">Search</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
                <div style="background-color:#F5F4F4; padding:8px; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 24px;">
                    <img src="../../images/govtlogo.svg" alt="" style="width: 100px;display: inline-block;">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
                        <h5
                            style="font-weight:500;margin:0; color:#003078;line-height:24px;margin-bottom:2px;font-size:16px;">
                            Ministry of Minister</h5>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;">Paybill Report for
                            Month Of January 2024</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;">Department : Department
                            Department Department</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;"><span>PAN Number :
                                BLRK07894F</span> | <span>Token Number : 12345</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="../../images/govtlogo.svg" alt="" style="width: 100px;display: inline-block;">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 24px;font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
                    <div style="padding: 20px 0 12px;border-top: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                        <p
                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color:#383F43; display: inline-block; width: 49%;">
                            Establishment No./ Name : 1</p>
                        <p
                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color :#383F43;text-align: right; display: inline-block;width: 49%;">
                            Final spanaybill To Be Represented To Treasury</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border-radius:12px 12px 0px 0px;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                        <div style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px; border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">DDO
                                    Code :</span>
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">
                                    0200KT0002t</span></div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Paybill
                                    Type : Regular Salary</span></div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; text-align: right;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Head Of
                                    Account : 2052-00-099-0-01</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding:8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">
                                <span
                                    style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Designation
                                    : Superintendent</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;  text-align: center;">
                                <span
                                    style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">PayScale
                                    : 37900 - 70850</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 19%; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Days
                                    Paid : 31</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 19%; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">With
                                    Hold Days : 0</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Next
                                    Increment Date : 01 Aug 2024</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table
                        style="border-collapse:collapse; padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px; width: 100%;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1; 
                        background-image: url(../../images/ProvisionalPayslipBG.svg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size: contain;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px !important;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">S.No</span></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span  style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Employee Name</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th  style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span  style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">KGID/ Metal No.</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"> </th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Basic Pay</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Allowances</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Gross Salary</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Deductions</span> 
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;"> 
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Recoveries</span> 
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Total Deductions</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Net Salary</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                <td style=" border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">1</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">Pooran Chandra M</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">KGID : 998807</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">1746805</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">39800</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;"><span>DA : 2587</span><br>
                                    <span> HRA : 9552</span><br>
                                    <span> CCA : 500</span><br>
                                    <span> Medical Allowance : 200</span><br>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">52039</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;"><span>PT : 200</span><br>
                                    <span>IT : 4500</span><br>
                                    <span>KGID : 2000</span><br>
                                    <span> EGIS : 240</span><br>
                                    <span> GPF : 10000</span><br>
                                    <span> LIC : 2374</span><br>
                                    <span>LIC SSYAX : 13</span><br>
                                    <span>CONDENDC : 100</span><br>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">19427</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">33212</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 24px;font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
                    <div style="padding: 20px 0 12px;border-top: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                        <p
                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color:#383F43; display: inline-block; width: 49%;">
                            Establishment No./ Name : 1</p>
                        <p
                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color :#383F43;text-align: right; display: inline-block;width: 49%;">
                            Final spanaybill To Be Represented To Treasury</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border-radius:12px 12px 0px 0px;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                        <div style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px; border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">DDO
                                    Code :</span>
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">
                                    0200KT0002t</span></div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Paybill
                                    Type : Regular Salary</span></div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; text-align: right;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Head Of
                                    Account : 2052-00-099-0-01</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding:8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">
                                <span
                                    style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Designation
                                    : Superintendent</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;  text-align: center;">
                                <span
                                    style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">PayScale
                                    : 37900 - 70850</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 19%; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Days
                                    Paid : 31</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 19%; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">With
                                    Hold Days : 0</span></div>
                            <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">
                                <span style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Next
                                    Increment Date : 01 Aug 2024</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table
                        style="border-collapse:collapse; padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px; width: 100%;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1; 
                        background-image: url(../../images/ProvisionalPayslipBG.svg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size: contain;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px !important;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">S.No</span></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span  style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Employee Name</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th  style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span  style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">KGID/ Metal No.</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"> </th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Basic Pay</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Allowances</span>
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Gross Salary</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Deductions</span> 
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;"> 
                                    <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Recoveries</span> 
                                     <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Total Deductions</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                                <th style="text-align: left; padding: 8px 12px;">
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Net Salary</span>
                                      <img src="../../images/data-table-arrow-down.svg" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 14px;"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                <td style=" border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">1</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">Pooran Chandra M</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">KGID : 998807</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">1746805</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">39800</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;"><span>DA : 2587</span><br>
                                    <span> HRA : 9552</span><br>
                                    <span> CCA : 500</span><br>
                                    <span> Medical Allowance : 200</span><br>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">52039</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;"><span>PT : 200</span><br>
                                    <span>IT : 4500</span><br>
                                    <span>KGID : 2000</span><br>
                                    <span> EGIS : 240</span><br>
                                    <span> GPF : 10000</span><br>
                                    <span> LIC : 2374</span><br>
                                    <span>LIC SSYAX : 13</span><br>
                                    <span>CONDENDC : 100</span><br>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">19427</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;padding:8px 12px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;">33212</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    </div>
 
</body>



</html>

You can see PDF image from here which gets downloaded. You can see it is not properly formatted as in HTML viewer. When I use Puppeteer package for doing this it downloads PDF as it is which I want, but my company wants to go with DevExpress only.
Please help as I am not getting how to do it with this package

I want to do it using dev express package

HTML/CSS support in the RichEditDocumentServer is pretty limited. It will not necessarily be able to handle some of the more complicated CSS formats. I would review the following: https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/15684/word-processing-document-api/html-import-and-export/html-support-limitations

yup thanks @Brendon for reply, after trying everything, I got that HTML to PDF in DevExpress is pretty limited. And this can't work like puppeteer or so.

I done this by doing a work around and re writing my HTML taking the width of A4 size paper which is 210mm. And now my HTML looks like -


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="font-md">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Result Master View</title>



</head>

<body class=" ">




    <div class="body-content">
        <main class="main-content">


            <div class=" customFormPage">
                
                <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;">
                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 24px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="background-color:#F5F4F4; padding:8px; text-align: center; ">
                                <td style="display: inline-block; font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; width: 60%;">
                                    <h5
                                        style="font-weight:500;margin:0; color:#003078;line-height:24px;margin-bottom:2px;font-size:16px;">
                                        Government of ABSDFASDFASD</h5>
                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;">Paybill
                                        Report
                                        for
                                        Month Of January 2024</p>
                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;">Department
                                        :
                                        Department
                                        Department Department</p>
                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;margin:0;margin-bottom: 2px;line-height: 24px;"><span>PAN
                                            Number :
                                            BLRK07894F</span> | <span>Token Number : 12345</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 24px;font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
                        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody style="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #F3F2F1;padding: 20px 0 12px;">
                                        <p
                                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color:#383F43; ">
                                            Establishment No./ Name : 1</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #F3F2F1;padding: 20px 0 12px;">
                                        <p
                                            style="margin: 0; font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color :#383F43;text-align: right; ">
                                            Final spanaybill To Be Represented To Treasury</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div>
                            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr style="border-radius:12px 12px 0px 0px;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">DDO
                                                Code :</span>
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">
                                                0200KT0002t</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Paybill
                                                Type : Regular Salary</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Head
                                                Of
                                                Account : 2052-00-099-0-01</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-radius:12px 12px 0px 0px;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Designation
                                                : Superintendent</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">PayScale
                                                : 37900 - 70850</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Days
                                                Paid : 31</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">With
                                                Hold Days : 0</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;">
                                            <span
                                                style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;color: #383F43;">Next
                                                Increment Date : 01 Aug 2024</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <table
                            style="border-collapse:collapse; padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px; width: 100%;border: 1px solid #F3F2F1; position: relative;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">S.No</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; padding: 3px;">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Employee
                                            Name</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">KGID/
                                            Metal No.</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Basic
                                            Pay</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Allowances</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px;">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Gross
                                            Salary</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Deductions</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                    line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Recoveries</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Total
                                            Deductions</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; padding: 3px; ">
                                        <span
                                            style="font-size: 12px;color:#000;font-style: normal;font-weight: 500;
                                     line-height: 24px;position: relative;text-transform: capitalize;word-wrap: break-word;">Net
                                            Salary</span>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody style="">
                                <tr style="border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;">
                                    <td style=" border: 1px solid #F3F2F1;font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">1</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">Pooran
                                        Chandra M</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">KGID :
                                        998807</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">1746805
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">39800
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;"><span>DA
                                            : 2587</span><br>
                                        <span> HRA : 9552</span><br>
                                        <span> CCA : 500</span><br>
                                        <span> Medical Allowance : 200</span><br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">52039
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;"><span>PT
                                            : 200</span><br>
                                        <span>IT : 4500</span><br>
                                        <span>KGID : 2000</span><br>
                                        <span> EGIS : 240</span><br>
                                        <span> GPF : 10000</span><br>
                                        <span> LIC : 2374</span><br>
                                        <span>LIC SSYAX : 13</span><br>
                                        <span>CONDENDC : 100</span><br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">19427
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;color:#383F43;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;
                                line-height: 24px;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: top;  padding: 3px;">33212
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="10">
                                        <img src="../../images/ProvisionalPayslipBG.svg" alt=""
                                            style="position: absolute;top: 79px; max-width: 590px; ">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="10">
                                        <img src="../../images/payslip-logo.png" alt="" style="position: absolute;bottom: 10px;left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    </div>


</body>



</html>



And c# code is -
private static async Task<byte[]> GeneratePDFFromHTMLAsync(string htmlString)
{
    IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment = _serviceProvider!.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()!;
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    RichEditDocumentServer richEditDocumentServer = new();
    richEditDocumentServer.HtmlText = htmlString;

    var document = richEditDocumentServer.Document;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.AllowTablesOutstepMargins = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.AllowHyphenationAtTrackBottom = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.AllowTextAfterFloatingTableBreak = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.DifferentiateMultirowTableHeaders = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.SplitPageBreakAndParagraphMark = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.SplitTableRowsAroundFloatingTables = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.SplitWrappedTablesAcrossPages = false;
    document.CompatibilitySettings.StretchLinesWithLineBreaks = false;

    document.Unit = DevExpress.Office.DocumentUnit.Millimeter;
    document.Sections[0].Page.Width = 210;
    document.Sections[0].Page.Height = 297;
    document.Sections[0].Margins.Top = 1.5f;
    document.Sections[0].Margins.Bottom = 1.5f;
    document.Sections[0].Margins.Left = 2;
    document.Sections[0].Margins.Right = 2;

    string filePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images", ConstantsHelper.Watermark);
    ImageWatermarkOptions imageWatermarkOptions = new ImageWatermarkOptions();
    imageWatermarkOptions.Washout = false;
    imageWatermarkOptions.Scale = 0.75;
    using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    document.WatermarkManager.SetImage(Image.FromStream(fs), imageWatermarkOptions);

    var options = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PdfExportOptions();
    options.ConvertImagesToJpeg = false;
    options.ImageQuality = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PdfJpegImageQuality.Highest;
    
    await richEditDocumentServer.ExportToPdfAsync(ms, options);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

It is not the perfect or best solution but it gets the job done.
